# undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I´m constantly stuck in this. I have many to many relations between Users, Friendship and Profile models. Nothing seems to work for me, Im getting a bit frustrated. Please can anyone help me?

the error is happening in this block of code

```
<%= friendship.friend.profile.name %>
```

The error msg are :

```
block in _app_views_users_show_html_erb__2756270183135360761_70272652488180
```

and

```
_app_views_users_show_html_erb__2756270183135360761_70272652488180
```

In my users/show.html.erb

```
    <h4> <%= current_user.profile.name%> Friends</h4>
         <ul>
           <% for friendship in @user.friendships %>
            <li>
              <%= friendship.friend.profile.name %>
              (<%= link_to "remove", friendship, :method => :delete %>)
           </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
```

in user.rb model

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
has_one :profile
```

in friendship.rb model

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

in profile.rb model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :friendships
 has_many :friends, through: :friendships
end
```

in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
 resources :users do
   resource :profile
 end
 resources :friendships
end
```

in users_controller.rb

```
def show
   @user = current_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that there are only two users in the app and that they are both friends, but according to the console output of `User.last.friendships` that you posted in the comments of Zaid's answer, there are 3 different user ids (6, 2, and 5). It seems like there is a ghost friendship leftover in your join table from a user that no longer exists. This would cause the error you're getting.

Because the error is happening when you try to call `profile` on `friend`, I'd assume the lost User is either 2 or 5.

You should remove the errant friendship manually and add a `dependent: :destroy` after `has_many :friendships` in your User model to avoid future repeats of the problem.

Comment: Hi @Scott Schupbach I believe this might be the right answer,  but I´m not able to remove the friendship manually. In my console I did `User.find(5).friendships.destroy` I´m able to save that but it is like the friendships dosen´t get destoyed. When I do User.find(5).friendships again the friendships are all still there

Comment: I still have `SELECT "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 5]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Friendship id: 9, user_id: 5, friend_id: 6, created_at: "2016-03-03 14:30:22", updated_at: "2016-03-03 14:30:22">, #<Friendship id: 12, user_id: 5, friend_id: 2, created_at: "2016-03-03 19:32:23", updated_at: "2016-03-03 19:32:23">]>
irb(main):026:0> 
` what does the `$1` mean in this line ? `"friendships"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 5]]`

Comment: Hi again @Scott Schupbach Your answer seems to have solved my problem...apparently I had to reload my console.... when I do `User.find(5).friendships` now I get  `SELECT "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 5]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`  and the error is gone.... Thank you so much

Comment: No problem. And to answer your question about the `$1`, this is a way of sanitizing data used in SQL queries to prevent SQL injection attacks. There's a good intro to the topic on [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html). And the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) goes into a little more depth if you're still curious.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

Your current_user is evaluating to nil, so its trying to put profile on nil. So you have to handle that

Comment: I´m not trying to access the current_user, I´m trying to link to a user that is friend to the current_user. The error is in this bit of code `<%= friendship.friend.profile.name %>`

Comment: then your `friendship.friend` is evaluating to nil, so before going to that check to make sure if the friendship has a friend, as in check for nil.

Comment: In my rails console I did `User.last.friendships` and figured that this user has a friend( there are only two users in the App and they are both friends). This is what I get in the console `[#<Friendship id: 10, user_id: 6, friend_id: 2, created_at: "2016-03-03 15:53:24", updated_at: "2016-03-03 15:53:24">, #<Friendship id: 13, user_id: 6, friend_id: 5, created_at: "2016-03-04 00:47:26", updated_at: "2016-03-04 00:47:26">]>`

Comment: hmm.. can you try adding checks in the html file that if current_user==nil or friendships.freind ==nil, then you will know its not those affecting you. Also check if @user is not nil